# Reference Excel Sheet name with INDIRECT in Formula - #VALUE Error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, valueerror, excel-indirect

I am replacing the sheet names with INDIRECT() in existing formulas of my workbook, to avoid #REF errors when I delete the sheets being referenced.
My Existing formula referencing directly the sheet

`=NUMBERVALUE(FILTER(INDEX('Complete-BOM'!$A$2:$AZ$3000;SEQUENCE(ROWS('Complete-BOM'!$A$2:$AZ$3000));$B$1);'Complete-BOM'!$A$2:$A$3000<>""))`

current formula with INDIRECT

`=NUMBERVALUE(FILTER(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&A10&"'!"&"$A$2:$AZ$3000");SEQUENCE(ROWS(INDIRECT("'"&A10&"'!"&"$A$2:$AZ$3000")));$B$1);INDIRECT("'"&A10&"'!"&"$A$2:$A$3000")<>""))`

Replacing with INDIRECT() in the current formula however is causing a #VALUE error due to
`SEQUENCE(ROWS(INDIRECT("'"&A10&"'!"&"$A$2:$AZ$3000")))` & `INDIRECT("'"&A10&"'!"&"$A$2:$A$3000")`

Any suggestions would be a great help

Comment: You need to fetch the SheetName w/o the cell references and append them next:
INDIRECT(A10)&"!$A$2:$AX$3000"&...

Comment: Hi, I tried as suggested, but it is giving #REF Error. Going to Calculation steps shows INDIRECT(Complete-BOM)&"!$A$2:$AZ$3000"... which then leads to #REF!&"!$A$2:$AZ$3000". Seems like the formula is not able to evaluate INDIRECT(A10) part

Comment: Ushay, I've identified the problem. The Indirect command is returning a string and you're concatenating 2 strings with the & operator so we wind up with "COMPLETE-BOM"&"!$A$2:$AZ$3000" which will not evaluate to a sheet!range reference. You could accomplish this with VBA and the Range() function but I don't know how to do the conversion in a formula. Still looking.